# Creating a list of unique pairs from a list of multi-value combinations in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, vba, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a bunch of rows in a Google Spreadsheet that look as such:

```
a,b,c,d
a,d
c,d
b,d,f
a,b,f,g,h,i
q,b,b
```

...And on.

I need a way to create a unique list of related pairs in this format:

```
a,b
a,c
a,d
b,c
b,d
c,d
b,f
d,f
a,f
a,g
a,h
a,i
```

...And on.

Any idea how I'd do that? I'm open to answers using Google Spreadsheet's scripting language, Excel 2004's scripting language or something else like PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to add in your above question that you are using Excel 2004?

Comment: Yeah, apologies for that -- I didn't realize there's a difference between the two versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this satisfies your platform requirements, but here is a *spreadsheet* formula that can be used in Google Spreadsheets itself (not in any Excel version though):

```
=ArrayFormula(SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",";A:A);",")))&","&TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",";A:A);","))));(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",";A:A);",")))<=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",";A:A);",")))))*REGEXMATCH(CONCATENATE(","&SUBSTITUTE(A:A;",";",,")&","&CHAR(9));"(,"&UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",";A:A);",")))&",[^\t]*,"&TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",";A:A);","))))&",)|(,"&TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",";A:A);","))))&",[^\t]*,"&UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",";A:A);",")))&",)"))&CHAR(9));CHAR(9)))))
```

It also assumes you don't want to list "b,a" as well as "a,b".

EDIT: These sort of formulae can be horribly inefficient for very large data sets, so consider only using if processing a few hundred rows or less.

Comment: Did you build that formula? Because it both amazes and scares me. Seriously brilliant work — it makes Google Spreadsheets stall for a solid 2 minutes with my 600-row data set, but works fantastic.

Comment: Selecting as answer because it works well and is easy to implement.

Comment: May have spoken too soon -- I've doubled my data set, and it just seems to have stopped working...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately these string manipulation formulae in GSheets can really suffer performance-wise with big data sets, to a point where the sheet grinds to a halt.  I apologise, I really should have qualified my answer in the first place, I will edit accordingly.  For big data sets, I would use a script solution, so feel free to change the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function to make pairs:

```
<?php
function make_pairs($str) {
  $chars = explode(',', $str);
  for ($i = 0; $i <= count($chars); $i++) {
    $f = array_shift($chars);
    foreach ($chars as $char) 
      echo "$f,$char\n";
  }
}

make_pairs('a,b,c,d');
```

Result:

```
a,b
a,c
a,d
b,c
b,d
c,d
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged the above question with `VBA`, here is a vba solution.

This will give you all the 45 unique combinations your above example is supposed to have.

**My assumptions**

**1)** Data is in Col A of Sheet1

**2)** Col A doesn't have any headers

**3)** Output to be generated in Col B

**4)** You are using Excel 2007 +

**5)** You are considering `b,b` as a valid combination because of `q,b,b`. If not then a small tweak needs to be added.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, nRow As Long, n As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim Myar() As String, TempAr() As String

    Set ws = Sheet1
    lRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    n = 0: nRow = 1

    With ws
        For i = 1 To lRow
            Myar = Split(.Range("A" & i).Value, ",")
            If UBound(Myar) > 1 Then
                For j = LBound(Myar) To UBound(Myar)
                    For k = LBound(Myar) To UBound(Myar)
                        If j <> k Then
                            ReDim Preserve TempAr(n)
                            TempAr(n) = Myar(j) & "," & Myar(k)
                            n = n + 1
                        End If
                    Next k
                Next j
            Else
                ReDim Preserve TempAr(n)
                TempAr(n) = .Range("A" & i).Value
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next i

        For i = LBound(TempAr) To UBound(TempAr)
            .Range("B" & nRow).Value = TempAr(i)
            nRow = nRow + 1
        Next i

        '~~> Remove duplicates
        .Range("$B$1:$B$" & UBound(TempAr) + 1).RemoveDuplicates _
        Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

        '~~> Sort data
        .Range("$B$1:$B$" & UBound(TempAr) + 1).Sort _
        .Range("B1"), xlAscending

        Debug.Print "Total Combinations : " & _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(2))
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

**FOLLOWUP**

Not sure if this will work with Excel 2004 but replace the line

```
        .Range("$B$1:$B$" & UBound(TempAr) + 1).RemoveDuplicates _
        Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

with

```
        For i = 1 To UBound(TempAr)
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("B" & i).Value) > 1 Then
                .Range("B" & i).ClearContents
            End If
        End With
```

Rest remains the same I guess. Test it and let me know if you get any errors?

Comment: That looks awesome, but any way you could make that compatible with Excel 2004? I'm on a Mac...

Comment: Sorry, I don't have Excel 2004. I have Excel 2011. I believe and I could be wrong but all the code should remain same accept `.Range("$B$1:$B$" & UBound(TempAr) + 1).RemoveDuplicates _
        Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo`. Instead of this, you will have to loop through the cells to delete the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks; I'm getting "sub or function not defined" on `Myar = Split(.Range("A" & i).Value, ",")` -- I think 2004 has no "split" function?

Comment: Yup :) See if this help? http://www.realgeek.com/forums/vba-split-function-missing-364456.html Replace that line with the code mentioned in the link.