# Cross Post: Slightly beyond finding unique combinations: Python/VBA (w/ bonus math q!)

Tags: python, excel, combinations, vba

This is a [cross post](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/725729-do-loop-loop-please-help.html) from another forum. The reason for doing so is that there is a S/O post that has very close to what I need to do: [S/O post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737363/creating-a-list-of-unique-pairs-from-a-list-of-multi-value-combinations-in-a-goo)

The cross post shows the example of what I need, but hopefully there is someone here who understands the logic displayed in the python example from S/O, but knows how to apply it in Excel.

The gist of it is taking ('a,b,c,d') and finding all of the unique pairs:

a,b
a,c
a,d
b,c
b,d
c,d

b,a should not be in the list, because a,b is already there etc.

There's great python code for this, but the vba example does quite work for what I need.

I'm working Windows, Excel 2010, in the end hope to be able to run the macros with a lot of columns.

---

*Bonus math question*:
I think the answer lies somewhere in combination/permutation formula land, but obviously I'm asking on this site for a reason:

How many sheets will I end up with if I create a new sheet with, say, 10 columns, and paired each column with each other column, only one time?

Is it
N! / r!(n-r)!

10! /2! (8!)

45?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Math: Yes, those are combinations and yes, `n!/(r!*(n-r)!)` is the answer.

VBA: Note that you can get all combinations providing that each element in a combination is always greater than previous element

Simple VBA function fro returning those combinations:

```
Function CombinationsOf2(Elements) As Variant()
     Dim i0 as Long, i1 as Long, ret(), cnt As Long
     For i0 = LBound(Elements) To UBound(Elements)-1
         For i1 = i0+1 To UBound(Elements)-1
             cnt=cnt+1
             ReDim Preserve ret(1 to cnt)
             ret(cnt)=Array(Elements(i0), Elements(i1))
          Next
      Next
      CombinationsOf2=ret
End If
```

Example:

```
'Checking uniqueness of elements if up to you
combs=CombinationsOf2(Array("a", "b", "c", "d"))
'Combs is an array of all combinations. Each combination is an array of elements.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the order doesn't matter, the **combination** is what you want.

If you want to apply it in Excel, I'd recommend a VB macro.

Comment: Yes, a VBA macro is what I am after. Don't know how to write it.